# Button event on release

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, click

Im working on an app to control some stuff over bluetooth.

Currently I have a form with some buttons. On each button I want to trigger an event when the button is pressed down and fire a different event when the button is released.

Is this possible?

Comment: this is a helpfull post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803157/xamarin-forms-button-pressed-released-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the "bluetooth" info should tell me.

But in C# Winforms, yes that is possible. See the MouseDown and MouseUp Events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button_events.aspx
(You may need to combine them with the keyboard events to capture them as well)

Comment: Well guess it has nothing to do with anything, just to explain :)
But thanks alot!