# Xamarin.Forms - Button Pressed & Released Event

Tags: c#, events, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I want to my event to trigger when button **pressed and released**, but I can only find **Click** event in Xamarin.Forms.

I believe there must be some work around to get this functionality. My basic need is to *start a process when button is pressed and stop when released*. It seems to be a very basic feature but Xamarin.Forms doesn't have it right now.

I tried TapGestureRecognizer on button, but button is firing only click event.

```
MyButton.Clicked += (sender, args) =>
{
  Log.V(TAG, "CLICKED");
};

var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
    Log.V(TAG, "TAPPED");
};
MyButton.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

Keep in mind that I need those events to be working in Android and iOS togather.

Comment: You would need to write a custom button renderer that exposes the underlying TouchDown and TouchUp events that Forms masks.

Comment: @jason can you suggest me some good tutorial or sample of custom renderer...???

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/

Comment: Thanks @Jason, It worked...

Comment: @umair.ali check out my answer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally I got the solution suggested by @Jason. Here we go...

1. Create sub class of Xamarin.Forms.Button in PCL project, with event
   handling capability

   ```
   public class CustomButton : Button
   {
       public event EventHandler Pressed;
       public event EventHandler Released;

       public virtual void OnPressed()
       {
         Pressed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
       }

       public virtual void OnReleased()
       {
         Released?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create platform specific button renderer in respective project

   For Andorid

   ```
   [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Button), typeof(CustomButtonRenderer))]
   namespace WalkieTalkie.Droid.Renderer
   {
       public class CustomButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
       {
           protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
           {
               base.OnElementChanged(e);

               var customButton = e.NewElement as CustomButton;

               var thisButton = Control as Android.Widget.Button;
               thisButton.Touch += (object sender, TouchEventArgs args) =>
               {
                   if (args.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
                   {
                       customButton.OnPressed();
                   }
                   else if (args.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
                   {
                       customButton.OnReleased();
                   }
               };
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   For IOS

   ```
   [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomButton), typeof(CustomButtonRenderer))]
   namespace WalkieTalkie.iOS.Renderer
   {
       public class CustomButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
       {
           protected override void    OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
           {
               base.OnElementChanged(e);

               var customButton = e.NewElement as CustomButton;

               var thisButton = Control as UIButton;
               thisButton.TouchDown += delegate
               {
                   customButton.OnPressed();
               };
               thisButton.TouchUpInside += delegate
               {
                   customButton.OnReleased();
               };
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Instantiate your custom button in your page

   ```
   var myButton = new CustomButton
   {
       Text = "CustomButton",
       HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
   };
   myButton.Pressed += (sender, args) =>
   {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Pressed");
   };
   myButton.Released += (sender, args) =>
   {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Pressed");
   };
   ```

Hope this help someone :)

Comment: It did help someone :)

Comment: this looks like the most inconvenient solution for a simple callback ever

Answer (score 7):

This can also be done with an effect instead of a full fledged custom renderer. See this post for an explanation of how to do it:

https://alexdunn.org/2017/12/27/xamarin-tip-xamarin-forms-long-press-effect/

In case that post ever goes away, here is the code that you can implement:

> In shared project:

```
/// <summary>
/// Long pressed effect. Used for invoking commands on long press detection cross platform
/// </summary>
public class LongPressedEffect : RoutingEffect
{
    public LongPressedEffect() : base("MyApp.LongPressedEffect")
    {
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(LongPressedEffect), (object)null);
    public static ICommand GetCommand(BindableObject view)
    {
        return (ICommand)view.GetValue(CommandProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCommand(BindableObject view, ICommand value)
    {
        view.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(LongPressedEffect), (object)null);
    public static object GetCommandParameter(BindableObject view)
    {
        return view.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCommandParameter(BindableObject view, object value)
    {
        view.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
    }
}
```

> In Android:

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyApp")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(AndroidLongPressedEffect), "LongPressedEffect")]
namespace AndroidAppNamespace.Effects
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Android long pressed effect.
    /// </summary>
    public class AndroidLongPressedEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        private bool _attached;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializer to avoid linking out
        /// </summary>
        public static void Initialize() { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the
        /// <see cref="T:Yukon.Application.AndroidComponents.Effects.AndroidLongPressedEffect"/> class.
        /// Empty constructor required for the odd Xamarin.Forms reflection constructor search
        /// </summary>
        public AndroidLongPressedEffect()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Apply the handler
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            //because an effect can be detached immediately after attached (happens in listview), only attach the handler one time.
            if (!_attached)
            {
                if (Control != null)
                {
                    Control.LongClickable = true;
                    Control.LongClick += Control_LongClick;
                }
                else
                {
                    Container.LongClickable = true;
                    Container.LongClick += Control_LongClick;
                }
                _attached = true;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoke the command if there is one
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Sender.</param>
        /// <param name="e">E.</param>
        private void Control_LongClick(object sender, Android.Views.View.LongClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invoking long click command");
            var command = LongPressedEffect.GetCommand(Element);
            command?.Execute(LongPressedEffect.GetCommandParameter(Element));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean the event handler on detach
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            if (_attached)
            {
                if (Control != null)
                {
                    Control.LongClickable = true;
                    Control.LongClick -= Control_LongClick;
                }
                else
                {
                    Container.LongClickable = true;
                    Container.LongClick -= Control_LongClick;
                }
                _attached = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> In iOS:

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyApp")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(iOSLongPressedEffect), "LongPressedEffect")]
namespace iOSNamespace.Effects
{
    /// <summary>
    /// iOS long pressed effect
    /// </summary>
    public class iOSLongPressedEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        private bool _attached;
        private readonly UILongPressGestureRecognizer _longPressRecognizer;
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the
        /// <see cref="T:Yukon.Application.iOSComponents.Effects.iOSLongPressedEffect"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public iOSLongPressedEffect()
        {
            _longPressRecognizer = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(HandleLongClick);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Apply the handler
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            //because an effect can be detached immediately after attached (happens in listview), only attach the handler one time
            if (!_attached)
            {
                Container.AddGestureRecognizer(_longPressRecognizer);
                _attached = true;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoke the command if there is one
        /// </summary>
        private void HandleLongClick()
        {
            var command = LongPressedEffect.GetCommand(Element);
            command?.Execute(LongPressedEffect.GetCommandParameter(Element));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean the event handler on detach
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            if (_attached)
            {
                Container.RemoveGestureRecognizer(_longPressRecognizer);
                _attached = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

> In XAML

```
<Label Text="Long Press Me!" effects:LongPressedEffect.Command="{Binding ShowAlertCommand}" effects:LongPressedEffect.CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
    <Label.Effects>
        <effects:LongPressedEffect />
    </Label.Effects>
</Label>
```

Answer (score 7):

Since Xamarin.Forms 2.4.0, The events [`Pressed`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.Button.Pressed) and [`Released`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.Button.Released) are offered out of the box (see [PR](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/446)).

Note: in order to achieve a Walkie Talkie effect you might want to use `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` (or via Prism's `IDeviceService`) to invoke consequent actions so the `Released` event will get called, otherwise the UI thread might be blocked.
Alternatively, you can declare the event handlers as `async` and `await` your invocations, to keep the UI thread unoccupied.

Answer (score 2):

```
Button button = FindViewById (Resource.Id.myButton);
button.Touch += (object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e) =>
{
if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
{
Toast.MakeText(this, "Key Up", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
        if(e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Key Down", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to intercept `Pressed` and `Released` Event on Xamarin I've used `Effects` property as explained in [this official Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/touch-tracking).

It's even more simple using [TouchTracking.Forms](https://github.com/OndrejKunc/SkiaScene#touchtrackingforms).

First add the library to your `Forms` project (not needed in platform specific project).

Next use it in Xaml asis

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.Effects>
        <tt:TouchEffect TouchAction="Handle_TouchAction" />
    </StackLayout.Effects>
    <Label Text="Sample"/>
</StackLayout>
```

With `tt` refering to :

```
xmlns:tt="clr-namespace:TouchTracking.Forms;assembly=TouchTracking.Forms"
```

Finally do your logic in code behind :

```
void Handle_TouchAction(object sender, TouchTracking.TouchActionEventArgs args)
{
    ;
}
```

`Handle_TouchAction` will be called everytime a touch action occurs, use `args.Type` to distinguish the action `Pressed`, `Released`,`Exited`...

*N.B `Effects` is available for various components not only `StackLayout`.*