# xamarin.forms - event listener for volume up and down keys

Tags: c#, events, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am writing an xamarin.forms app and I want to open 'special settings' page when press both volume up and down buttons.

Is there any way to do that in xamarin.forms?

For now, I have done an event listener, which works correctly. Now last thing i need to do is to pass the binding context to Settings Page.

```
List<Keycode> _pressedKeys = new List<Keycode>();


        public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
        {
            if(keyCode == Keycode.VolumeDown)
            {
                _pressedKeys.Add(keyCode);
                CheckBoth();
                return true;
            }

            if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeUp)
            {
                _pressedKeys.Add(keyCode);
                CheckBoth();
                return true;
            }


            return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
        }

        public override bool OnKeyUp(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeDown)
            {
                _pressedKeys.Remove(keyCode);

                return true;
            }

            if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeUp)
            {
                _pressedKeys.Remove(keyCode);


                return true;
            }

            return base.OnKeyUp(keyCode, e);
        }

        public void ChangePage()
        {
            ((App)App.Current).ChangeScreen(new SettingsPage());
        }

        public void CheckBoth()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_pressedKeys.Contains(Keycode.VolumeDown) &&
                    _pressedKeys.Contains(Keycode.VolumeUp))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("It works!");
                    ((App)App.Current).ChangeScreen(new SettingsPage());
                    _pressedKeys.Clear();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
```

Solved. I added following line:

```
var vm= App.Current.MainPage.BindingContext as MainViewModel;
```

Comment: What you did till now? Show your effort?

Comment: I added to my MainActivity.cs `OnKeyUp` method, which Barney Chambers suggested. Now I am digging google to find answer how to change page.

Comment: Please, update your question with new informations. Your code should be helpful too.

Comment: question is updated

Comment: Please have a look at this link hope its help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/38816510/3701787

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to go platform specific with this implementation, but here is the Android implementation for handling volume button presses:

```
public override bool OnKeyUp(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeDown)
    {
        //Dostuff();

        return true;
    }

    if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeUp)
    {
        //Dostuff();

        return true;
    }
    return base.OnKeyUp(keyCode, e);
}
```

Comment: ok.I added your code to .android main activity. And good thing its detecting clicks. But now.. How to change the page now?

Comment: @GrzegorzG. Use dependency service for volume key listener and use an event/delegate in your pcl interface, by subscribing to which, you can navigate through pages