# Sub Class for Xamarin.Forms, Event handler for buttons

Tags: c#, events, bluetooth, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make a Bluetooth controller for Android for a school project. See picture:

[image]

axml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="70sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bar"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/text" />
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_forward"
    android:rotation="90"
    android:progress="100"
    android:id="@+id/bar" />
<Button
    android:text="Forward"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_fire"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/button_forward" />
<Button
    android:text="Fire"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_backward"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/button_fire" />
<Button
    android:text="Backward"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/button_backward" />
<Button
    android:text="Left"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_backward"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_fire"
    android:id="@+id/button_left" />
<Button
    android:text="Right"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_backward"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_fire"
    android:id="@+id/button_right" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I need to get 2 event handlers on the buttons, for when pressed and when released. The idea would be like in this post: [Xamarin.Forms - Button Pressed & Released Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803157/xamarin-forms-button-pressed-released-event)
But I don't know how to make the subclass under Xamarin.Forms.

Here is the code of my `MainActivity`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Bluetooth;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;

namespace Bluetooth_Controller
{
    [Activity(Label = "Bluetooth_Controller", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        BluetoothAdapter BTAdapter;
        Button button_Forward, button_Fire, button_Backward, button_Left, button_Right;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Initialize Components
            Initialize();

            // Get local Bluetooth Adapter
            BTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter; // Default adapter
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            button_Forward      = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button_forward);
            button_Fire         = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button_fire);
            button_Backward     = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button_backward);
            button_Left         = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button_left);
            button_Right        = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button_right);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify OnCreate to obtain a reference to the button. Then call SetOnTouchListener to provide a handler for touch event:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
   base.OnCreate(bundle);
   SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
   button_Forward = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button_forward);
   button_Forward.SetOnTouchListener(this);
}
```

Change MainActivity.cs so that it implements View.IOnTouchListener, and add the OnTouch method that is required by the interface. Add the following code to reposition the Button in response to the touch moving across the screen:

```
public class Activity1 : Activity, View.IOnTouchListener
{
   public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
   {
       switch (e.Action)
       {
           case MotionEventActions.Down:
                //Do whatever you want in Down Key
               break;
           case MotionEventActions.Up:
              //Do whatever you want in Up Key
               break;
       }
       return true;
   }
}
```