# xamarin forms Listview multi select

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have xamarin.forms app which contains a listview. What I am trying to implement is multi select the listview and do some action. Currently the listview contains a Item tapped event , which will open another page.How can I implement the multi select the listview when user hold the list view item cell just like in every other apps(eg; messages, whatsapp etc). My rough plan is , if somehow I achieved the long press event, I will show checkbox inside listview.

So, what will be the best approach of multiselect listview? Is it possible to enable it with press holding the listview item cell?

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT 1**: I used Collection view as suggested by *Jason*. It provides selection mode as single and multiple.It works fine. But how can I change the selection mode of collection view from single to multiple when user press and hold a single cell?

**EDIT 2**:As suggested by *LeonLu-MSFT* For long press event, I used the effect from *alexdunn.org*. But I am not using MVVM pattern. I am implementing it on code behind.So according to alexdunn.org article [link](https://alexdunn.org/2017/12/27/xamarin-tip-xamarin-forms-long-press-effect/), It works according to command. How can I get the long press event on backend c# using command?

**My List view with long press effect.**

```
 <ListView  x:Name="TimesheetListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding} " 
              HasUnevenRows="True"                                                                        
              HeightRequest="{Binding Path=Height, Source={x:Reference ListLayout}}"
              CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
              SeparatorVisibility="None"                                       
              BackgroundColor="Transparent"                      
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"                        
              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <ViewCell.View>
                                    <Frame  BorderColor="LightGray" 
                                    CornerRadius="5" BackgroundColor="White" 
                                    Margin="2" Padding="5" HasShadow="False"
                                    Text="Long Press Me!" effects:LongPressedEffect.Command="{Binding ShowAlertCommand}"
                                    effects:LongPressedEffect.CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                    >
                                                         <Frame.Effects>
                                    <effects:LongPressedEffect />
                                    </Frame.Effects>        
                                    <Label Text="Lognpress" FontSize="Micro" TextColor="Black"  VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    </Label>                                
                                    </Frame>
                                </ViewCell.View>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

How can I get the command in backend?

Comment: use CollectionView - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#multiple-selection

Comment: @Jason Hi, Thanks for the info about collection view. How can I make the selection when user click and hold the view cell?

Comment: If you do not want to use custom renderer to achieve the long click event, please waitting for this feature.https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3480, you can also try this workaround https://alexdunn.org/2017/12/27/xamarin-tip-xamarin-forms-long-press-effect/

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I used  Xamarin.Forms Long Press Effect from alexdunn.org . But I am not using MVVM. I could't got the clicked event on backend cs. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting Long press event for any control, Created a class in Shared code named **CustomView**

```
public class CustomView: ContentView
    {
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> LongPressEvent;

        public void RaiseLongPressEvent()
        {
            if (IsEnabled)
            LongPressEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

    }
```

In android, 
Created a class named **LongTouchCustomRender**

```
 public class LongTouchCustomRender : ViewRenderer<CustomView, Android.Views.View>
    {
        private CustomViewListener _listener;
        private GestureDetector _detector;

        public CustomViewListener Listener
        {
            get
            {
                return _listener;
            }
        }

        public GestureDetector Detector
        {
            get
            {
                return _detector;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                GenericMotion += HandleGenericMotion;
                Touch += HandleTouch;

                _listener = new CustomViewListener(Element);
                _detector = new GestureDetector(_listener);
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            GenericMotion -= HandleGenericMotion;
            Touch -= HandleTouch;

            _listener = null;
            _detector?.Dispose();
            _detector = null;

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        void HandleTouch(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            _detector.OnTouchEvent(e.Event);
        }

        void HandleGenericMotion(object sender, GenericMotionEventArgs e)
        {
            _detector.OnTouchEvent(e.Event);
        }
    }

    public class CustomViewListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
    {
        readonly CustomView _target;

        public CustomViewListener(CustomView s)
        {
            _target = s;
        }

        public override void OnLongPress(MotionEvent e)
        {
            _target.RaiseLongPressEvent();

            base.OnLongPress(e);
        }
    }
```

In ios Created class named **LongTouchCustomRender**

```
  public class LongTouchCustomRender : ViewRenderer<CustomView, UIView>
        {
            UILongPressGestureRecognizer longPressGestureRecognizer;
            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomView> e)
            {
                longPressGestureRecognizer = longPressGestureRecognizer ??
                    new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(() =>
                    {
                        Element.RaiseLongPressEvent();
                    });

                if (longPressGestureRecognizer != null)
                {
                    if (e.NewElement == null)
                    {
                        this.RemoveGestureRecognizer(longPressGestureRecognizer);
                    }
                    else if (e.OldElement == null)
                    {
                        this.AddGestureRecognizer(longPressGestureRecognizer);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Inside my Viewcell of listview,

```
<local:CustomView LongPressEvent="Handle_LongPress" />
```

Handled the click like this

```
void Handle_LongPressEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //handle long press event here
}
```

Got this answer from [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845595/is-there-a-way-to-recognize-a-short-or-long-press-on-a-screen-with-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve it directly through Portable but able to do through platform specific.

**Note:** For multiple selection like checkbox, you can create property in the model class like IsSelected then based on this property, you make the checkbox check and uncheck.

Create CustomView for render your template in the ListView like below, In that, expose a command for handling the hold operation in MVVM. And as well as interface for raising the hold action from renderer.

```cs
public interface ICustomViewController : IViewController
{
    void SendHoldAction();
}

public class CustomView : ContentView, ICustomViewController
{
    public CustomView()
    {
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty HoldCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create("HoldCommand", typeof(Command), typeof(CustomView), null);

    public Command HoldCommand
    {
        get { return (Command)GetValue(HoldCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HoldCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public void SendHoldAction()
    {
        HoldCommand.Execute(this.BindingContext);
    }
}
```

And XAML part of the custom view like below,

```xml
<ListView x:Name="listView" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <local:CustomView HoldCommand="{Binding BindingContext.HoldCommand, Source={x:Reference listView}}">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </local:CustomView>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The Renderer part of **Android** below,

```cs
public class CustomViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomView, Android.Views.View>
{
    public CustomViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (this.Control == null)
                this.SetNativeControl(new Android.Views.View(this.Context));

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.LongClickable = true;
                Control.SetOnLongClickListener(new ContentViewLongClickListener(this));
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (this.Control != null)
            {
                Control.SetOnLongClickListener(null);
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private class ContentViewLongClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnLongClickListener
    {
        private readonly CustomViewRenderer viewRenderer;

        public ContentViewLongClickListener(CustomViewRenderer customViewRenderer)
        {
            viewRenderer = customViewRenderer;
        }

        public bool OnLongClick(Android.Views.View v)
        {
            viewRenderer?.Element?.SendHoldAction();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Likewise you achieve it for **iOS**.

Comment: Thanks ganesan for the answer. +1.  I done it another way

Answer (score 0):

You can add boxview into your layout. When clicked, change the color like it is selected (You can also directly change the color of your layout, you don't need to add boxview). Then handle all selected bars with a button.